# MySQL getting sum of tables with the same id

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have four tables `person,loan,ca,payments`

I would like to get the sum of all payments amounts and cash advance amounts which has the same ID as the loan joined with a person from a specific date.

Here is my code, but the sum is calculated incorrectly:

```
SELECT pd.*,
    l.total_loan_amount,
    sum(c.ca_total_amount) AS ctot,
    sum(p.payment_amount)
FROM personal_data pd
LEFT JOIN loans l
    ON pd.id_personal_data = l.id_personal_data
LEFT JOIN ca c
    ON l.id_loan = c.id_loan
LEFT JOIN payments p
    ON l.id_loan = p.id_loan
WHERE l.loan_date = curDate()
    AND (
        c.ca_date = curDate()
        OR c.ca_date IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        p.payment_date = curDate()
        OR p.payment_date IS NULL
        )
GROUP BY pd.id_personal_data
```

Comment: l.loan_date ever null?  Code looks good...

Comment: are you getting any error or output is wrong?

Comment: output is wrong...i computed the actual data manually..and its not the same as the output

Comment: im trapping the null value in case there are no payment or cash advance in my where condition..

Comment: Note that one would typically GROUP BY *all* the unaggregated columns in the SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that may sometimes retrieve invalid results because `id` may or may not sometimes be present on other table.

Try using a subquery for each column you want to retrieve.

```
SELECT  pd.*,
        l.total_loan_amount,
        c.totalCA,
        p.totalPayment
FROM    personal_data pd
        LEFT JOIN loans l
            ON pd.id_personal_data = l.id_personal_data
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id_loan, SUM(ca_total_amount) totalCA
            FROM    ca 
        --  WHERE   DATE(ca_date) = DATE(CURDATE()) OR
        --          ca_date IS NULL
            GROUP BY id_loan
        ) c ON l.id_loan = c.id_loan
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id_loan, SUM(payment_amount) totalPayment
            FROM    payments 
        --  WHERE   DATE(payment_date) = DATE(CURDATE()) OR
        --          payment_date IS NULL
            GROUP BY id_loan
        ) p ON l.id_loan = p.id_loan
WHERE DATE(l.loan_date) = DATE(curDate())
```

I think `dates` on every payment and cash advance are irrelevant because you are looking for its totals based on the `date of loan`

Comment: but still is it possible to get the total payments,cash advance base on the loan and base on current date or specific date?

Comment: @GeorgeDanGilDuran yes. have you tried on the query above? give me a feedback so ill update if something is missing.

Comment: it just gives me empty result...i made some correction though the last select statement would be from payments table,am i right?

Comment: @GeorgeDanGilDuran yes sorry for the typo, can you give me some of your records so i can check it?

Comment: Personal_date(uid,Name)-(1,'George'),(2,'Willy') : Loan(lid,loan_amount,date,uid)-(1,2000,date,1),(2,1000,date,2) : CA(cid,ca_amount,date,lid)-(1,500,date,1),(2,500,date,1),(3,500,date,2),(4,100,date,1):payments(pid,pay_amount,date,lid)-(1,200,date,1),(2,200,date,1).....sorry for the format man..

Comment: the result would be: Name - Loan Amount - total CA - total Payments that would be (George - 2000 - 1100 - 400) (willy - 1000 - 500 - 0)

Comment: @GeorgeDanGilDuran thanks for the records. [see this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/948aa/8). i've got the result you want.